# setalpha on XML drawable, discrepancy between Android API 15 and API 19

Tags: android, android-drawable, alpha

I'm trying to programmatically set transparency to this XML drawable (hexgrid.xml):

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/hexgrid1"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Part of RelativeLayout where it's used:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/boardf"
    android:background="@drawable/hexgrid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code:

```
boardf = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.boardf);
Drawable background = boardf.getBackground();
background.setAlpha(Math.round(255*hexgridtrans/100f));
```

On my phone (API 19) it works fine, but on my tablet (API 15) sadly it doesn't.

With a `hexgridtrans` of 25 value (and 64 passed as param to the `setAlpha(int alpha)` method), this is what I get:

[image: Example of Drawable.setAlpha(int alpha) discrepancy between API versions]

On the left, alpha is set to 25% and working as expected, while on the right - same code and same values - is more or less of 6%.

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm aware of `Drawable.mutate()`, but I don't make any use of the drawable prior to this drawing and, nonetheless, I've tried it and it doesn't make any difference here.

`Drawable.setAlpha(int alpha)` is working normally on both devices when I use it with PNG files, so I suspect the problem may be related to the use of a XML drawable.

Comment: so it looks like it is 25% of 25%... try to pass 128 and check if your real transparency is 0.5 * 0.5

Comment: @pskin Well observed, it is. If I pass 128, I get the same results on tablet than with 64 on phone. It looks like alpha is being applied twice, but only on one device.

Comment: try `getPaint().getAlpha()` on your `BitmapDrawable` (i hope `Drawable background = boardf.getBackground();` is a `BitmapDrawable`)

Comment: i mean: `BitmapDrawable d = (BitmapDrawable)boardf.getBackground(); Log.d(TAG, "alpha " + d.getPaint().getAlpha());`

Comment: @pskink, thanks for code :). API 15 returns an alpha of 64. API 19 also returns 64.

Comment: what does `View#getLayerType()` return on both versions? refer to `View#setLayerType` to see how it could affect your views

Comment: `View c = (View) boardf; Log.i("MyActivity", "getLayer() " + c.getLayerType());` returns 0 on both.

Comment: ok last shot: `View#getAlpha()`

Comment: `(View) boardf.getAlpha` returns 1.0 on both.

Comment: and how about `Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(...); d.setAlpha(64); boardf.setBackground(d);` ?

Comment: `boardf.setBackground(Drawable d)` requires API level 16. I tried on tablet with deprecated `setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d)` but it doesn't show anything using XML drawable. With a PNG it works though. I'm doing it like this: `Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hexgrid); Drawable e = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm); e.setAlpha(64); boardf.setBackgroundDrawable(e);`

Comment: so the problem is in xml you are using: to verify that try for testing `android:src="@drawable/copyOfHexgrid1` where copyOfHexgrid1.png is a copy of Hexgrid1.png and it should be used only in this one place

Comment: Just tried with new XML drawable hexgridtest.xml, hexgridtest1.png and `android:src="@drawable/hexgridtest1"`. No difference, same results as shown in question.

Comment: so you have to use `BitmapDrawable` created in the java code...

Comment: Using all the `Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory...` code of four comments above with new hexgridtest shows the same result as that test: no drawable shown at all.

Comment: you said `With a PNG it works though`, so it works or not?

Comment: Yes, with a PNG it works, but it has worked always, as I stated in question. The problem is I need the XML drawable, mainly for the `android:tileMode="repeat"`.

Comment: you did `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hexgrid);` where `R.drawable.hexgrid` points to xml which is bad: it should be a png file

Comment: @pskink Improved names. Now `hexgridxml` contains `android:src="@drawable/hexgridpng"`. I made more tests. `Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hexgridpng); Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm); d.setAlpha(64);` and `Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hexgridpng); d.setAlpha(64);` do nothing, hexgridxml is shown with full alpha 255, even if `boardf.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hexgridxml);` set only after them. `Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hexgridxml); d.setAlpha(64);` shows same behaviour as in question.

Comment: post your **full** code with `Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hexgridpng);`

Comment: @pskink `Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hexgridpng); Drawable e = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm); e.setAlpha(64); boardf.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hexgridxml);`

Comment: you don't use `e`, you have to pass it to `setBackgroundDrawable()` method

Comment: @pskink Yes, same code as above but with `boardf.setBackgroundResource(e)` of course does show *hexgridpng* as background, and with the right alpha I guess (hard to say with an oversized half hex taking all the screen). But this has never been my problem. I thought you were aiming at the png drawable in cache (same reason why sometimes Drawable.mutate() is needed), but I'm afraid I don't follow you anymore. Sorry for ruining your Saturday!

Comment: now check `BitmapDrawable` API, in particular `setTileMode*` methods

Comment: @pskink Ok, now full grid shows, but I get the same weird alpha of 16 on tablet API 15. Full code: `Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hexgridpng); BitmapDrawable e = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm); e.setAlpha(64); e.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT); boardf.setBackgroundDrawable(e);`

Comment: so definitely `BitmapDrawable ` is broken, try using `ShapeDrawable` with setup `ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory`: you have to return `BitmapShader` from `resize` method

Comment: @pskink Here we go: `ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory sf = new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() { @Override public Shader resize(int width, int height) { BitmapShader d = new BitmapShader(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hexgridpng), Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT); return d; } }; ShapeDrawable e = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape()); e.setShaderFactory(sf); e.setAlpha(64); boardf.setBackgroundDrawable(e);` This gives me a nice hexgrid, but still showing wrong alpha of 16 on API 15. On API 19 working great.

Comment: no, you know its not possible that those two classes have the same error, now try this: http://pastebin.com/HkB2N3pu and please dont tell it does not work

Comment: No change, showing alpha of 16 on API 15. Using `MyDrawable` from Pastebin. Code: `MyDrawable md = new MyDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.hexgridpng); md.setAlpha(64); boardf.setBackgroundDrawable(md);`

Comment: @pskink If I comment the last code, I get no hexgrid at all, so it's not a case of duplicated code elsewhere. Same happens with the 'ShapeDrawable' code above. Checked for all other mentions of `boardf`, but everything seems ok, I don't touch background alpha in any other place.

Comment: then run this: http://pastebin.com/raw/TbemNn8w and check `/sdcard/bitmap.png` with paint / gimp / whatever

Comment: @pskink I had to charge the device and get the code working (the path part was tricky), but the resulting image is perfect: `bitmap.png` shows a correct alpha of 64 (25%), while on screen it's still of 6%.

Comment: so i guess the problem is with the view you are trying to set the `Drawable` as a background (boardf).... try: http://pastebin.com/N0rT42j2, also when you run it paste the output of `adb shell dumpsys activity top` command

Comment: No, same problem as in question when moving it to the onCreate.

Comment: ok so change `MyDrawable` (posted yesterday here: http://pastebin.com/raw/HkB2N3pu) by adding `canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);` before calling `canvas.drawPaint(paint);` inside `draw()` method

Comment: With `Color.black` can't see a thing. Changed it to `canvas.drawColor(0xFF728F3F);` (green), and I get the same 6% alpha result.

Comment: and what you see if you remove everything from `draw` method? what about `adb shell dumpsys activity top` command?

Comment: Well, I see nothing. I commented out everything on onCreate, but your code. Now the app shows a perfect black screen and nothing else.

Comment: ok so i run out of ideas... try 3 different layer types `View#setLayerType` and/or try to switch off hwd-accel for entire app and see if it changes anything https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: @pskink adding `view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` does show correct alpha. With `LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE` and `LAYER_TYPE_NONE` I get the wrong one. Hardware acc. is enabled in Android Manifest, BTW.

Comment: so you can go back to your original xml (hexgrid.xml) and set software layer

Comment: @pskink Yeah, I guess so. But I enabled Hardware acceleration precisely for the `boardf` view. That's where all the action happens. Oh well!

Comment: If you can turn all this mess into an answer, I'll be more than glad to accept it.

Comment: honestly,  i am dog tired,  write an self answer instead,  maybe it helps someone

Comment: @pskink No way. I asked two other questions in SO that I had to answer myself. This is the first time I get help in here, so NO, I'll wait for your answer tomorrow or in some days. Have a nice Sunday, and thanks a lot :)

Comment: well most of my comments here were not my knowledge but rather "hit and hope" - nothing more than wild guess :-)

Comment: @pskink You telling me? I've learned more Android classes in the last two days than in the last two months :]

Comment: yep, happily, all good things come to an end... btw i was asking about layer type on my 4th comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42723620/setalpha-on-xml-drawable-discrepancy-between-android-api-15-and-api-19?noredirect=1#comment72584609_42723620) but forgot to test with 3 of them - what a waste of time...

Comment: @pskink Not a total waste, at least I learned some things. And with hardware accel disabled in Android Manifest I still get the same alpha bug, so I totally discarded that possibility in my mind.